# Cannot return correct result from SQL query in PHP

Tags: php, sql, ajax, json, cordova

I have created a table and there are some data inside

however, by using the following link, i always get the result of {"flag":"0","msg":"Incorrect id."}, no matter the id is correct or not

i wondering where the problems happen? thanks

http://mydomain.com/ajax_login_json.php?user_name=admin&password=admin

```
    <?php session_start();

 //Connect to database from here
    $link = mysql_connect('****', '****', '****'); 
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //select the database | Change the name of database from here
    mysql_select_db('****'); 

//get the posted values
$user_name=htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_name'],ENT_QUOTES);
$pass=$_POST['password'];

//now validating the username and password
$sql="SELECT user_name, password FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name='".$user_name."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

printf("Select returned %d rows from tbl_user.\n", $result->num_rows);

//if username exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    //compare the password
    if(strcmp($row['password'],$pass)==0)
    {
        // Return success message
        $message = array("flag" => "1", "msg" => "Login successfully.");
        echo json_encode($message);
         //Regenerate session ID to prevent session fixation attacks
        //session_regenerate_id();


        //now set the session from here if needed
        //$_SESSION['u_name']=$user_name; 
        //$member=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        //$_SESSION['u_id']=$member['id'];
        //$name_show=$member['first_name'].' '.$member['last_name'];
        //$_SESSION['name']=$name_show;
            //Write session to disc
            //session_write_close();

        }
    else
        // Return error message
        $message = array("flag" => "0", "msg" => "Incorrect password.");
        echo json_encode($message);
}
else    //if username not exists
{       // Return error message
        $message = array("flag" => "0", "msg" => "Incorrect id.");
        echo json_encode($message);
}
mysql_close($link);     
?>
```

Comment: Please tell me you're not really authenticating via query string...

Comment: I would highly advise rethinking that approach.  If you do it that way then usernames and passwords will be all over the place (on the wire, in web server logs, etc) in plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems

```
$sql="SELECT user_name, password FROM tbl_user WHERE user_name='".$user_name."'";
```

result is 0 if you don't get any db connection error. Try to print `$user_name` to see if it is in your DB table first.